# What code is font locking quoted strings in my custom mode buffer?

Tags: font-lock

I'm experimenting with making a major mode that does some simple syntax
highlighting.  My keywords are being highlighted just fine, but the
quoted string in the example below is also being highlighted (but not by
me).

Here is my code:

```lisp
(defvar ct-mode-nset-keywords
  '("name" "type" "testme" "doc"))

(defvar ct-mode-nset-font-lock-defaults
      `((
         ;; highlight the second token on the name line
         ("^name:[ \t]*\\([-a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)"
          . (1 font-lock-function-name-face))
         ;; highlight all the other keywords
         ( ,(regexp-opt ct-mode-nset-keywords ) . font-lock-keyword-face)
         )))

(defun ct-nset-mode ()
  "Major mode for working with nameset files."
  (kill-all-local-variables)
  (setq major-mode 'ct-nset-mode)
  (setq mode-name "MyMode")
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults)
       ct-mode-nset-font-lock-defaults))
```

Here is my sample buffer. My keywords (name, type, doc) all highlight as
expected. The second token on the name line also highlights as expected.

The problem is that the quoted string on the third line is being
highlighted too (including the double quotes) by something.

```lisp
name: wonky
type: string
doc : "this is a string"
```

In the sample buffer, if I evaluate the variable font-lock-defaults, I
get the expected value:

```lisp
font-lock-defaults
((("^name:[     ]*\\([-a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)" 1
    font-lock-function-name-face)
("\\(?:doc\\|\\(?:nam\\|t\\(?:estm\\|yp\\)\\)e\\)" 
    . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

What code is font locking the quoted string?  (My mode line says "MyMode
Abbrev"), so I don't think any other modes are active. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This highlighting is syntactic font-lock highlighting.  It occurs when variable `font-lock-keywords-only` is `nil`.  This variable is normally set automatically by Font Lock mode based on the `KEYWORDS-ONLY` element in ‘font-lock-defaults’.

See the Elisp manual, node [Syntactic Font Lock](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntactic-Font-Lock.html).

As that node explains, your major mode can use the function specified by variable `syntax-propertize-function` to apply
‘syntax-table’ text properties to override the buffer’s syntax table in
special cases.  (Syntactic highlighting uses the syntax table.)

See node [Font Lock Basics](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-Lock-Basics.html) of the Elisp manual for how to set variable `font-lock-keywords-only` to non-`nil` indirectly, by setting up the value of `font-lock-defaults` so that it has a non-`nil` `KEYWORDS-ONLY` part.

That means just using a value such as `t` as the second element of `font-lock-defaults` -- just after the list of keywords for normal (non-syntactic) font-lock highlighting.  For example:

```el
(defvar ct-mode-nset-font-lock-defaults
  `(( ;; highlight the second token on the name line
     ("^name:[ \t]*\\([-a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)" . (1 font-lock-function-name-face))
     ;; highlight all the other keywords
     ( ,(regexp-opt ct-mode-nset-keywords ) . font-lock-keyword-face))
    t)) ;; <================ non-nil KEYWORDS-ONLY
```